# Where exactly does the "awakening" happened in Star Wars: The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, snoke

At the scene where Kylo Ren and Snoke were talking, Snoke said that..

> **SNOKE**: There's been an awakening. Have you felt it?

And Kylo answered with a yes.

**Where exactly in the movie did this *awakening* happened?**